# Android Resource Namespace

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, namespaces

I recently started programming an Android application and am currently stuck with one question.

The resources I have in my project are all in the same namespace. The names I used for elements I have in **strings.xml**, for example, I can't use again in say **my_strings.xml**.

I had originally hoped that I access the strings in **strings.xml** through `@strings/myString` and the ones in **my_strings.xml** through `@my_strings/myString`.

Is there any way to achieve what I would like to have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, There is a way! But it depends on what you intend to make the difference. Android has a full-blown Resources management Logic. So if, say Strings in `values/strings` are english, but you want to provide german strings too, just make another `values-de` folder and put the german Strings with the same identifier inside. Depending on system language, Android picks the right ones.

To get an Overview of what is possible have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

It tells you all possible combinations of values-postfixes. If you can't archive what you want with that mechanism, you only could prefix the identifier of your strings. I.E. `my_string_key` and `string_key`.

One Last Note: the file name in which you put values is competely irrelevant to the system. You are able to mix Strings, colors, dimensions, arrays and styles in one file called `foobar.xml` as long as the file resides inside a `value-XXX`folder!

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. That helped a lot. I understand the possibilities and limits of the resource management now.